# How to compile Python with (Active)Tcl 8.6?

Tags: centos, python, python3, tcl

I'm trying to compile Python 3.5.0 on CentOS 6 with Tcl 8.6. I did

```
./configure --with-tcltk-includes=I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/include --with-tcltk-libs=L/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/libs --prefix=/home/aivar/localpython
```

After installing, IDLE -> Help -> About shows me that I'm using Tk 8.5.7.

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configure script requires a leading '**`-`**' before those `I` and `L` options:

```
--with-tcltk-includes=-I/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/include --with-tcltk-libs=-L/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/libs
                      ↑                                              ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct path is `/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/lib` at least for version *8.6.6.8606*
of ActiveTcl on Ubuntu Linux 64-bit